# sets of axioms for LADR automated theorem provers

Tags: reference-request, automated-theorem-proving

I am pretty new to ATP, but I'm really enjoying playing around with prover9. I have found a nice set of axioms for basic information-theoretic proofs [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506143736/http://itl.kaist.ac.kr/ittp.html), I was wondering if there are some collections of axioms for other purposes too, e.g. probability theory.

I found a gigantic set of axioms for TPTP programs [here](https://www.tptp.org/cgi-bin/SeeTPTP?Category=Axioms), but prover9 is a LADR program...

Comment: Don't forget to also use mace4, I found it even more useful than prover9. LADR just means "Library for Automated Deduction Research", and has little to do with the file format. [The-E-theorem-prover](http://wwwlehre.dhbw-stuttgart.de/~sschulz/E/E.html) can directly use TPTP programs. But I found it quite easy to convert between the different input formats, so I wouldn't worry too much about the file format. [Here](https://gentzen.wordpress.com/2014/12/06/algebraic-characterizations-of-inverse-semigroups-and-strongly-regular-rings/) I describe some of my own experiments with prover9 & co.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are saying that it is sufficient to translate files from the TPTP format to a format that prover9 would understand?

Comment: I think the TPTP library also contains a utility called [TPTP2X](http://www.cs.miami.edu/~tptp/TPTP/TR/Utilities.shtml), which can convert to the input format of many different ATP systems. As you can see from the linked page, prover9 is also among the supported TPTP2X Output Formats.